# Trouble with race condition in component lifecycle methods - How to get data in time?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I've tried a number of configurations to solve this issue, but basically I'd like parent component to run an async function, morph the result, and pass that as props to my child. I'm not really sure where to incorporate lifecycle methods, namely because ComponentDidMount will run, set state, and re-render the parent component just fine and a console.log of state inside the parent render method shows the state updated correctly with my fields. But the child component renders and shows an empty array in props.

Any ideas on this one?

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface CustomState {
    fields: any;
}

class Parent extends React.Component<{}, CustomState> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            fields: [],
        };
    }

    public async componentDidMount() {
        let fields = await asyncCall();

        const viewFields = this.buildViewFields(fields);

        this.setState({
            fields: viewFields,
        });
    }

    private buildViewFields(fields) {
        const viewFields = fields.map((f) => {
            return {
                name: f.Title,
            };
        });

        return viewFields;
    }

    public render() {
        // ISSUE: this.state.fields if logged here shows viewfields
        return <ChildComponent fields={this.state.fields}></ChildComponent>;
    }
}

export default Parent;
```

Here's my child component:

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            viewFields: this.props.fields,
        };
    }

    public render() {
        console.log(this.state); // DOES NOT HAVE VIEWFIELDS
        return (
            <GrandChildComponent
                fields={this.state.viewFields}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do this part

```
        this.state = {
            viewFields: this.props.fields,
        };
```

You can just use `props.fields` right away inside your `ChildComponent`.

What happens right now is:

1. Parent renders, `fields` is empty
2. Child renders, it sets `viewFields` to empty `fields` array inside constructor
3. Parent fetches actual `fields` and calls setState with them, rerenders self and Child
4. Child *rerenders*, but constructor is not invoked again.

If you want to actually setState inside Child from Parent props you need to use lifecycle method `componentDidUpdate`. It is rarely needed though and usually is just bad practice.

Comment: You are correct, but I was really hoping to be able to set this as part of state for later use. May just give up and go with using props directly as off the top of my head, I can't think of a reason to need this to be in the child's state just yet.

Comment: I guess it doesn't really matter. I can control and manipulate state in the parent and just tell the child what it needs via props. Which is in line with what I need anyways. Anyways, thanks.